# Нужны ли дефисы в предложении?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Уважаемые знатоки русского языка, уместны ли будут в этом предложении дефисы для подчеркивания антитезы? Или и так все наглядно и доходчиво?

> Крылатая надоеда летала вокруг Этайн и пиликала на разные лады, что лапочка (?) Джаред выиграл, а злюка (?) Мидир проиграл, проиграл!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никаких дефисов не надо. Розенталь и ПАС едины в отошении дефиса перед именами собственными. И антитеза на это не может повлиять.

> Сочетания этого типа с собственными именами обычно пишутся раздельно: старик Державин (П.), крошка Цахес (персонаж одноименной повести Гофмана), простак Ваня и т. п.; но: матушка-Русь (Некр.). ([ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp120.php))

Comment: Слушаю и повинуюсь. )))

Answer (score 2):

Да ни за что! Или

> и так все наглядно и доходчиво!

Налицо нормальные определения.

**[Дефис не ставится, если...](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=85)**

> ...предшествующее однословное приложение может быть по значению
>   приравнено к определению-прилагательному.

Comment: Это да! И злой Мидир вполне соответствует правилу. А вот лапочный Джаред вызывает вопросы.ИМХО )) Возможно, есть правило о написании существительных общего рода с определяемыми словами. Я бы почитала. ))

Answer (score 1):

*Джаред-лапочка*, **но** *лапочка Джаред*.

Answer (score 1):

Крылатая надоеда летала вокруг Этайн и пиликала на разные лады, что **лапочка  Джаред** выиграл, а **злюка  Мидир** проиграл, проиграл!

**В правилах Розенталя и ПАС задача имеет разное решение:**

**Розенталь (дефис не пишется):** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

4. Дефис не пишется:
   1) если **предшествующее однословное приложение** **может быть по значению приравнено к определению-прилагательному:** красавец мужчина (ср.: красивый мужчина), старик отец, гигант завод (но: завод-гигант), бедняк сапожник, богатырь всадник, крошка сиротка, хищник волк, искусник повар.
   Следует, однако, заметить, что приложение-существительное может по смыслу отличаться от определения-прилагательного; так, в предложении Татьяна по воле барыни была выдана замуж за пьяницу башмачника (Т.) сочетание пьяница башмачник (постоянный признак) не то же, что пьяный башмачник (временный признак).

**ПАС (дефис пишется)** http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp120.php

в) сочетания с однословными приложениями, **предшествующими определяемому слову,** напр.: старик-отец, красавица-дочка, умница-сын, герой-лётчик, мудрец-писатель, проказница-мартышка, самодурка-мачеха, трудяга-следователь, профан-редактор, пройдоха-управляющий. Такие приложения носят оценочный характер.

**Сочетания этого типа с собственными именами** обычно пишутся раздельно: старик Державин (П.), крошка Цахес (персонаж одноименной повести Гофмана), простак Ваня и т. п.; но: матушка-Русь (Некр.).

**Комментарий**

В ПАС правило упрощается, **но решение Розенталя представляется более логичным**. Приложение ― это определение, выраженное существительным. Его нормальная позиция ― перед определяемым словом (раздельное написание), инверсированная позиция ― после определяемого слова (дефисное написание). Мы таким образом можем определить, где существительное, а где его определение.

На практике это правило применяется для имен собственных (***царевич Иван и Иван-царевич)*** и приложений, которые имеют **явно определительное значение** (по Розенталю), причем совершенно **необязательно, чтобы оно действительно заменялось однокоренным прилагательным** (сравнить: богатырь всадник).

***Лапочка Джаред*** ― это милый Джаред (явное определение).

Comment: Розенталь и ПАС едины в отошении имен собственных. ПАС: Сочетания этого типа с собственными именами обычно пишутся раздельно: старик Державин (П.), крошка Цахес (персонаж одноименной повести Гофмана), простак Ваня и т. п.; но: матушка-Русь (Некр.).

Comment: В отношении имен собственных они едины, но чем объясняется  отмена общего правила для приложений при их определительном значении (вида старик-отец)? Где здесь приложение, а где существительное?  Получается, что отец - приложение? (Зато всё простенько, думать не надо, все будем грамотными). Что касается заданного вопроса, то его при помощи ПАС и обсуждать невозможно, там нет термина "определительное значение".

Comment: Ссылка на ПАС мне очень помогла. Я во всем разобралась. ;)